# customize the default toolbar icon images of a matplotlib graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

i want to change the default icon images of a *matplotplib*.
even when i replaced the image with the same name and size from the image location 
i.e. *C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\home.png* 
its still plotting the the graphs with the same default images.

If I need to change the code of the image location in any file kindly direct me to the code and the code segment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that exactly what you will have to do will depend on you gui toolkit.  The code that you want to look at is in `matplotlib/lib/matplotlib/backends` and you want to find the class that sub-classes `NavigationToolbar2` in which ever backend you are using.